# Sends AJAX, PHP query and return JSON and AJAX do not understand with "dataType: 'json'"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm new here and jQuery development, I have a question, Why can not I use the **dataType:'json'** nor **$.parseJSON** to handle a return of a query from **PHP** to **AJAX (jQuery)**.

**reader.js**

```
$(function(){

    //Modal form which encapsulates the loading of information occurs
var modal = $('.modal');
    //Encapsulates the existing list or the list elements, each element has an "edit" button
var lista = $('.lista');

lista.on('click','.actionedit',function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    var li = lista.find('li[class*="j_'+id+'"]');

    $.ajax({
        url:            'php/controller.php',
        data:           'acao=consulta&editid='+id,
        type:           'POST',
        //contentType:    'application/json; charset=utf-8;',
        dataType:       "json",
        error:          function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            alert('Erro: "'+ xhr.status + '"\nMensagem: " ' + thrownError +'"');
                        },
        beforeSend:     function(){ 
                            li.css("background","#0F6") },
        success:        function( carga ){

                                //alert( carga );
                            alert( carga.nome );

                            //modal.fadeIn("slow");
                            //modal.find('form span[class="filebar"]').text(carga.file);
                            //modal.find('form input[name="titulo"]').val(carga.title);
                            //modal.find('form textarea').append(carga.description;
                        },
        complete:       function(){ loader.fadeOut("slow"); },
    });

    return false;
});
});
```

**controller.php**

```
<?php
require_once("conexao.php");

switch($_POST['acao']){

case 'consulta':
    //Validates query, that returns a json string...
    $editid = $_POST['editid'];
    $qr = "SELECT * FROM mod6_uploads WHERE id = '$editid'";
    $ex = mysql_query($qr);
    $st = mysql_fetch_array($ex);

    //Return array in json format string for testing...
    $u['file'] = 'File';
    $u['title'] = 'File title';
    $u['description'] = 'File Description';

    echo json_encode($u);

break;
default:
    echo 'Error querying';

}
```

Thus, the alert returns me the following message:

```
Error: "200"
Message: "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character"
```

If I comment the dataType: "json", it returns me the following warning: undefined

And if I change the alert to "alert (carga.nome)" to "alert (load)", it returns me the following:

```
{"name": "File", "title": "File Title", "description": "File Description"}
```

Also, as I said earlier, if I use the `$.ParseJSON` or `JSON.parse` not have any return, or the error or the success.

Anyone out there have come across something like this?
If anyone could help me I would be very grateful!

Comment: Where in your php are you setting the "name" property? or did you just leave that off

Comment: You need to use `dataType: "json"` ***OR*** `$.parseJSON`, not both. Exactly the way you have it written in your question should work just fine.

Comment: Most likely something else in your php is returning an extra character, which in turn makes your json invalid.

Comment: Why did you comment out `contentType` ?

Comment: also, your error condition should return json too.

Comment: You've told jquery to expect JSON in the response. If your server is outputting **ANYTHING** else before or after your actual json string, then you're doing to get this warning - JSON syntax is very strict, and somethign like a PHP warning or other "junk" will cause the jquery decode of the json to fail. Make sure there's no PHP warnings, unicode BOMs, etc... being output.

Comment: @AlexW the contentType he has is incorrect for the request he's sending, so it being commented out is a good thing.

Comment: If you are using Google Chrome you can hit F12, then choose Network tab and find current request, then choose Response tab to see what is exactly returned by server. Maybe this information will be useful for you

Comment: @KevinB The character set being UTF-8 is not a bad thing. Especially, given that he is getting an unexpected character error.

Comment: Right, but application/json is a bad thing, since he's not sending json.

Comment: use http://jsonlint.com/ to verify your JSON response, using the f12 from @KevinB. It will also format it for you so you can see where your error is.

Comment: @AlexW The `Content-type` in `$.ajax` refers only to what the browser sends, not what the server returns.

Comment: What do you get from `alert(carga)`?

Comment: @Barmar I know what it is but in some cases, HTTP uses the Content-Type header in character detection. [Simple explanation](http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/character-encoding.html). It might be relevant to this, it may not. But it might be useful for future visitors to this question that have an `application/*` content type.

Comment: Content-Type is used in both directions: the browser sends it to the server to describe the type of the input, and the server sends it to the browser to describe the response. The two are not related.

Answer (score 1):

I'd change this line:

```
data:  'acao=consulta&editid='+id,
```

By this:

```
data:  {acao: 'consulta', editid: id},
```

As your id comes from an href, it would be better if it's automatically escaped.

Also, instead of this:

```
echo 'Error querying';
```

something like:

```
echo json_encode(array('Error querying'));
```

so it doesn't give JSON parse errors (return as javascript array of errors).

Also, ensure your `mod6_uploads` table has a `nome` field.

I see the rest is fine.

Cheers

PS: I suggest you to use a dev tool for debugging. One very easy is chrome's, just press F12, click the network tab and then run your ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `dataType:'json'`, `success` callback will only trigger if the server response is a valid JSON.
So if `error` callback is triggering, your response is 'populated' with extra data that makes JSON invalid.
In this case try to comment `dataType:'json'` and write in your `success` callback:

```
alert(carga)
```

or

```
console.log(carga)
```

This will output the server response and you will be able to see what's wrong with it.

Also if you deside to use JSON, try to use JSON everywhere in that file and avoid such code:

```
echo 'Error querying';
```

Otherwise you may get unexpected result